# Unity generate 2 different keys with same name in regedit

Tags: unity-game-engine, regedit

Simly I am using playerprefs` string saving code as follow:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString(variablename, variablevalue);
```

### Problem

But I realized that somehow it generated 2 different hkeys for some variable names but not for others.

### Question

What effects the value added at  the end of variable names in regedit?

### Further Information

I could erase the hkeys but it would be generated somehow later and it create a problem for me.

[image: player prefs problem][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjBoG.png)

Key bird1_10 and 12 repeat but 13 and 14 not(I update the values multiple times)

### Update

Actually I am using the same PlayerPrefs and variable names generated dynamically from 2 long strings.
1st- Comes from a text file and each line seperated by enters.
2nd- Writed by hand divided by "\n".

The two texts are working correctly for the following format(first 2 chars create varible name the other 2 variable value):
1-1-1:0. I realize that if the value by hand does take empty value like 1-1 it works corretly but if the value comes from the text take emty value like 1-1 its variable name in regedit  created differently. Strange, I worked all day but coulnot solve.

Comment: Is the line in your snippet the only line where you use a PlayerPrefs set method?

Comment: Actually I am using the same PlayerPrefs and variable names generated dynamically from 2  strings.
1- Comes from a text file and each line seperated by enters.
2- Writed by hand divided by "\n".

The two texts are working correctly(first 2 char create varible name the other 2 for value):  
1-1-1:0

Comment: Thank you Tobias I coludnot write description as commet I update question

Answer (score 0):

Finnally I solved the problem: 
When I pass empty PlayerPref value to device from the "inline text" with divided by "/n" Unity create a different hkey for that(I think it is a bug), so I just assign a default (like 0 or " ") value instead of empty values and problem is solved. Thanks Tobias.